# ./run.sh: line 1: java: command not found

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, java, 32-bit

I'm trying to install `worksnaps` client so I can start working on a project. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32bit system.

Installation and Configuration for `worksnaps` are simple :

> Download the Worksnaps Client package. The package is in zip format.
>   With the user login that is going to use the Worksnaps Client, run the
>   command "unzip WSClient_linux_.zip" to unzip the package. You
>   should be able to see a directory "Worksnaps" created. Execute command
>   "cd Worksnaps/bin" Execute command "chmod +x run.sh" Execute command
>   "chmod +x p.sh" Launch the Worksnaps Client by executing command
>   "./run.sh" (Note: please do not click any Jar file to launch the
>   program.)

After I do this I'm getting this error in mine terminal

```
./run.sh: line 1: java: command not found
```

Link to the [instruction's](http://www.worksnaps.com/www/download_instruction_linux.shtml) for `worksnaps`.They said here `Worksnaps client version 1.1.20140511 or newer runs on both 64-bit or 32-bit Java environment. On a 64-bit Linux system, 64-bit Java environment is preferred.` But they are not specific about what version does not working, I assume you can install both on 32-bit and 64-bit system, and there is just one version to download `worksnaps verison 1.1.201440511'.

Can someone help me overcome this.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have OpenJDK / Oracle Java installed. What's the first line of `run.sh`?

Comment: it's just run.sh

Comment: in folder I have `capture_ext.sh`, `lib/`, `p.sh`, `run.bat`, `run.sh`, `worksnaps.cfg` and `WSClient.jar'

Comment: `java -Djava.library.path="./lib" -jar "./WSClient.jar"`

Comment: `The program 'java' can be found in the following packages` ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way to find the problem:

1. `run.sh` is a script. So do a `more run.sh` to see what is on the line number is shows in the error.
2. The line will start with a command (`java` most likely).
3. Do a `java --version`.

If this errors out you did not install "java" and the program depends on it.

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```

would install Open JDK 8 and make the script work.

There is also

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

for version 6 or 7 but 8 should be the best one.

---

For Ubuntu 14.04 you will need

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre` did it.

Comment: Yeah I noticed later you are on 14.04.